# Celery worker running tensorflow unable to create CUDA event

Tags: python, tensorflow, celery

I am loading tensorflow model to the celery worker but when I try to run a task on the worker, it shows the following error:

```
[2018-09-19 10:29:39,753: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: analyze_atom[f6bb76cc-aa16-4761-a7cf-0ed111886ff8]  
[2018-09-19 10:29:41,198: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] paper checkpoint1 takes 1.433300495147705 senconds
2018-09-19 10:29:41.318467: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:81] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-09-19 10:29:42.650529: E tensorflow/stream_executor/event.cc:40] could not create CUDA event: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
[2018-09-19 10:29:42,673: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-2' pid:3782 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2018-09-19 10:29:42,704: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1223, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

This is a tensorflow model and when the celery is started the model is loaded successfully on GPU, here is the work started log:

```
totalMemory: 15.90GiB freeMemory: 15.61GiB
2018-09-19 10:35:38.431559: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-19 10:35:38.793007: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-19 10:35:38.793054: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-09-19 10:35:38.793063: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-09-19 10:35:38.793487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15131 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:08.0, compute capability: 6.0)
2018-09-19 10:35:40.552010: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-19 10:35:40.552073: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-19 10:35:40.552080: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-09-19 10:35:40.552085: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-09-19 10:35:40.552327: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15131 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:08.0, compute capability: 6.0)
2018-09-19 10:35:41.304281: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-19 10:35:41.304336: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-19 10:35:41.304344: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-09-19 10:35:41.304348: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-09-19 10:35:41.304574: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15131 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:08.0, compute capability: 6.0)
2018-09-19 10:35:43.013963: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-19 10:35:43.014025: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-19 10:35:43.014033: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-09-19 10:35:43.014038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-09-19 10:35:43.037554: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15131 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:08.0, compute capability: 6.0)
2018-09-19 10:35:43.916442: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-19 10:35:43.916500: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-19 10:35:43.916507: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-09-19 10:35:43.916512: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-09-19 10:35:43.916752: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15131 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:08.0, compute capability: 6.0)
2018-09-19 10:35:44.137238: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-19 10:35:44.137296: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-19 10:35:44.137304: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-09-19 10:35:44.137308: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-09-19 10:35:44.137563: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15131 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:08.0, compute capability: 6.0)
[2018-09-19 10:35:44,650: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://yjyx:**@118.178.129.156:5672/yjyx
[2018-09-19 10:35:44,667: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-09-19 10:35:45,716: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync with 1 nodes
[2018-09-19 10:35:45,717: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync complete
[2018-09-19 10:35:45,750: INFO/MainProcess] celery@yjyx-gpu-1 ready.
```

I also see that the GPU memory is allocated:

[image]

I am using supervisor to run celery and here is supervisor config:

```
[program:celeryworker_paperanalyzer]

process_name=%(process_num)02d
directory=/home/yjyx/yijiao_src/yijiao_main
command=celery worker -A project.celerytasks.celery_worker_init -Q paperanalyzer -c 2 --loglevel=INFO

user=yjyx
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/yjyx/log/celeryworker_paperanalyzer0.log
stderr_logfile=/home/yjyx/log/celeryworker_paperanalyzer1.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB                           ; maximum size of logfile before rotation
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10                              ; number of backed up logfiles
stdout_logfile_backups=10

autostart=false
autorestart=false
startsecs=5

stopwaitsecs=8
killasgroup=true
priority=1000
```

Here is celery task code snippet:

```
@shared_task(name="analyze_atom", queue="paperanalyzer")
def analyze_atom(image_urls, targetdir=target_path, studentuid=None):
    try:
        if targetdir is not None and os.path.exists(targetdir):
            os.chdir(targetdir)
        paper = Paper(image_urls, studentuid)
        for image_url in paper.image_urls:
            if type(image_url) == str:
                paper.analyze(image_url)  # tensorflow inference get called within paper.analyze
            elif type(image_url) == dict:
                paper.analyze(image_url['url'], str(image_url['pn']), image_url.get('cormode', 0))
        return paper.data
    except Exception as e:
        logger.log(40, traceback.print_exc())
        logger.log(40, e)
        return {}
```

I am sure the whole procedure should be OK, actually, I used opencv within paper.analyze to handle the job, and, it works well, now I just change opencv to tensorflow.

Env: Python3.6.4; Tensorflow 1.8; celery 4.0.2; OS: Centos 7.2

Any help will be really appreciated. :-)

Thanks.

Wesley

Comment: Removing the CUDA tag from this question wasn't an accident. This isn't a CUDA programming question and shouldn't be tagged as one

Comment: Sorry, I just googled a lot and man pages lead me to think related to CUDA. But now I find it nothing to do with CUDA. Might be related to all fork scenarios. I will remove CUDA tag. Thx.

Comment: @Wesley Can you share Paper class or create simple function to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ChillarAnand Sorry for the late response and my mistake not showing Paper class. Now I find the root cause: for all modules/functions referred by celery task, we cannot import tensorflow from the module level.

Comment: i was able to get celery to use gpu with `--pool solo` flag per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471308/868736

Answer (score 0):

Changing things to single-threaded is an easy fix. You can resolve this issue by adding `-P solo` to your celery command

i.e:

```
celery -app APP worker -P solo --loglelvel=info
```

Note: `APP` is your app name.