# Using PyTorch with Celery

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, pytorch, celery

I'm trying to run a PyTorch model in a Django app. As it is not recommended to execute the models (or any long-running task) in the views, I decided to run it in a Celery task. My model is quite big and it takes about 12 seconds to load and about 3 seconds to infer. That's why I decided that I couldn't afford to load it at every request. So I tried to load it at settings and save it there for the app to use it. So my final scheme is:

- When the Django app starts, in the settings the PyTorch model is loaded and it's accessible from the app.
- When views.py receives a request, it delays a celery task
- The celery task uses the settings.model to infer the result

The problem here is that the celery task throws the following error when trying to use the model

```
[2020-08-29 09:03:04,015: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task app.tasks.task[458934d4-ea03-4bc9-8dcd-77e4c3a9caec] raised unexpected: RuntimeError("Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  /*...*/
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 191, in _lazy_init
    "Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. " + msg)
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

Here's the code in my settings.py loading the model:

```
if sys.argv and sys.argv[0].endswith('celery') and 'worker' in sys.argv: #In order to load only for the celery worker
    import torch
    torch.cuda.init()
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
    load_model_file()
```

And the task code

```
@task
def getResult(name):
    print("Executing on GPU:", torch.cuda.is_available())
    if os.path.isfile(name):
        try:
            outpath = model_inference(name)
            os.remove(name)
            return outpath
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error", name, "doesn't exist")
    return ""
```

The print in the task shows `"Executing on GPU: true"`

I've tried setting `torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` in the settings.py before and after the `torch.cuda.init()` but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting this method works as long as you're also using `Process` from the same library.

```
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process
```

Celery uses "regular" `multiprocessing` library, thus this error.

If I were you I'd try either:

- [run it single threaded](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-concurrency) to see if that helps
- [run it with eventlet](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-with-eventlet) to see if that helps
- [read this](https://medium.com/snaptravel/scaling-allennlp-pytorch-in-production-56746c76d710)

Comment: There's no need of "torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')", or "from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process". Using eventlet and concurrency 0 solved the problem

Comment: single threaded works as well - `celery -A your_proj worker -P solo ` 

is there any way to know which one is a better solution here - single threaded in solo pool vs eventlet/gevent with concurrency 0?

Answer (score 8):

A quick fix is to make things single-threaded. To do that set the worker pool type of celery to solo while starting the celery worker

```
celery -A your_proj worker -P solo -l info
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the Celery worker itself is using forking. This appears to be a currently [known issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6036) with Celery >=4.0

You used to be able to configure celery to spawn, rather than fork, but that feature (`CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV`) was [removed in 4.0](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#features-removed-for-lack-of-funding).

There is no inbuilt options to get around this. Some custom monkeypatching to do this is probably be possible, but YMMV

Some potentially viable options might be:

- Use celery `<4.0` with `CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV` enabled.
- Launch celery workers on Windows (where forking is not possible anyhow)