# It is possible to run celery on gpu?

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, gpu, django-celery

The question is - **It is possible to run celery on gpu?**

Currently in my project I have settings like below:

```
celery -A projectname worker -l error --concurrency=8 --autoscale=16,8 
--max-tasks-per-child=1 --prefetch-multiplier=1 --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

This is django project.

One single task take around 12 s to execute (large insert to postgresql).

What I want to achive is multiply workers as many as possible.

Comment: Hello, as far as I understand from this question, Celery doesn't work with GPU, right? Have you found any way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with GPU. But you can scale horizontally by increasing the number of machines executing tasks in the queue.

Comment: fyi. i was able to get celery to use gpu with --pool solo flag per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471308/868736 That said, for most cases, performance/cost ratio for inference in cpu instances usually ain't that bad.

Answer (score 2):

No. Celery offers no way to run anything on GPU. However, nothing prevents you to use Keras, TensorFlow, or PyTorch in your Celery tasks (as a matter of fact I see many questions here about these projects and Celery).

Comment: My problem is that I have too many tasks. One task takes a few seconds so I try to increase the number of workers.

Comment: If tasks are not heavy on CPU you can increase them to few hundred. Also, keep in mind that you can change the concurrency type to thread or eventlet/gevent.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the number of workers like this...

```
celery -A projectname --workers=3
```

Comment: But this is still limited by number of CPU cores.